# Return nth occurrence of same name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a workbook for customer callbacks. On sheet3 (D2:D301) I have a master list of customer names. Some customers have the same name. On sheet1 (E4:E305) I am keeping track of which customers I have contacted. On sheet2 (V2:V301), I have a list of names I still need to contact. This list is generated using this formula:

```
 =iferror(if (vlookup (sheet3!D2,sheet1! $E $4:$E $305,1,0)=sheet3!d2)
```

Unfortunately, this formula doesn't account for customers with the same name. And I can't figure out how to make it do so.

Comment: Are you calling the customers in the same order as the master list? If you are then you could count how many instances of the name are above each entry and find that iteration on sheet3. Is there maybe some other unique piece of information you could use to differentiate such as their telephone numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give them unique ID's. I have to use just the info provided. And no, it's not necessarily in order.

Comment: Actually, I think its close enough to calling in order for that to work. But I can't figure out the formula to do that. It would need to count the occurrences on sheet3, then see if there are that many occurrences on sheet1. I don't know how to write that formula.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the formula would look like, but there's potentially a solution using INDEX,SMALL,IF, and ROW nested into an IF statement. Basically INDEX is a much more versatile formula than VLOOKUP, and nesting SMALL/IF/ROW can give you the nth matching value. You'd have to add some sort of IF statement to make that initial match across sheets 1 and 3 though. And really, pnuts is right - it'd be much easier to just add a column on sheet1 and give everything a unique value (read more here: http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list)

Comment: Why can't you give them Unique ID's?  Even if you hide the column you can calculate against it.  You seem to have control over the formulas so why not us a new tab or sheet to clean up your data?